# Flash AS3: How can I get functions to exit the game loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, flash, scene

I am working on a Flash project with multiple scenes. I use the function:

```
function gameloop(e:Event)  {
```

to add my functions in to one scene, but when switching the scene I am rained on with errors because the objects used in the other scene are no longer on screen. Is there an opposite to the code I pasted here to take functions out of the game loop for my other scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function gameloop(e:Event)  {
    if(currentFrame != 2){
        return;
    }
}
```

Check **currentFrame** in the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply but that will bring up "Duplicate Function Definition." This is because I use that first line of your code to add things to the GameLoop, is there any other way to take things out of the GameLoop?

Comment: Did you copy my function to another function? Copy only if(currentFrame... to your gameloop.

Comment: Thanks again so much and your right. But this doesn't seem to work. I am using hitTestObject functions and so when going to the next scene it doesn't have that object it says hitTestObject must be non-null, this doesn't seem to fix that. I use for example exitlevel();  and such underneath function gameloop(e:Event) to call to the actual function. Is there a place I should put those in the code you wrote here?

Comment: I understand this now, but is there anyway to have more than one of these if current frame codes working separately under function game loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the way you're implementing `gameLoop` is via an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener.

If this is the case, then you simply need to remove the event listener:

`stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);`

I'm using `stage` as an example, you'll want to change that to whatever object on which you originally added the listener.

Comment: Yes I would but I need to continue using the game loop on other scenes, Thankyou for replying though!

Comment: I suggest you post some more code to give us a better idea of what you're dealing with.